# Image processing / matching in android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-image, pattern-recognition

I'm thinking of doing an image processing app for android as my senior year project. The basic functionality I'd like is for the user to be able to take a photo from the camera and then try to match it to certain preexisting images in the database.

I'll be using it for distinct objects, not objects with varying characteristics like pen, car, etc. Rather objects like maybe the Eiffel tower. The app should be able to recognize an Eiffel tower based on the photo taken from the camera and comparing it to an already existing pic of the Eiffel tower.

Is this project feasible in a 6 month time frame or is it feasible at all?
What APIs does android provide to get this job done ?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with image recognition but RenderScript might be a powerful tool for this task.

Comment: I don't know if detection of complex objects like the Eiffel tower is feasible but the most popular image processing library is opencv, see e.g. http://robocv.blogspot.de/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html there is also some binding for Android http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html - also remember that Android devices are far more restricted in terms of processing power & resources

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a neural network, and than training it for the objects you want to recognize.
Also, you should try implement pattern recognition natively for better performance. Still, I'm not confident that it would work well in terms of recognition mistakes and fast execution. Also, you would need large training datasets for every object you want to recognize, pictures from different angles, taken during day and night, in different weather occasions... Recognition performance could be improved if you take into account gps location from which is picture taken (Eiffel tower surely is not visible from London). If you want to make this to work it would take a tremendous amount of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing as a project in 3 months or so. There is not Andriod API. But you can build an application for it. In my project I send the snapshot image to a server to do that match, the server have a database for image build with "bag of words" model and using SIFT/SURF as feature extraction algorithms. The server will reply with information to the mobile client as need. There is a tutorial how to build the a similar thing [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~dmchen/teaching.html)